# thread::hardware_concurrency() as template parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, concurrency

I have a template class with an unsigned int parameter for the number of threads. I want to use it to create a static array for the threads.

I can neither use `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` as default value,

```
template <typename T, size_t num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()>
    class  Some_class{
      T values[num_threads];
      ...
}
```

nor give it to my class as parameter.

```
template <typename T, size_t num_threads>
        class  Some_class{
          T values[num_threads];
          ...
    }

Some_class<int,std::thread::hardware_concurrency()> instance;
```

The problem is that `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`s return value is not const.

The compiler says:

```
error: call to non-constexpr function ‘static unsigned int std::thread::hardware_concurrency()’

note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’
```

Is there another static way to get the number of available threads for my template?

Comment: you can only use *constant expressions* in C++ templates. unfortunately `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` isn't a *constant expression*, rather it can only be evaluated at runtime

Comment: Which OS are you using, and which compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no static way to get the number of logical CPUs on a system. This number can easily change between compilation and execution, e.g. if the binary is executed on a different system.

You could get the number of logical CPUs of system that compilers the code from the build system, for instance using [CMake's ProcessorCount](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ProcessorCount.html) and put that into a define.

Comment: Sounds good! How can I use this number in my program as a define like you already said?

Comment: I just managed to do get it. I set the number of threads like in the example in the [link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ProcessorCount.html) and added:

`set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -DTHREADS=${N})`

Now I can use it in my template. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad you got it working. Just a little hint: you can use `add_definitions(-DTHREADS=${N})` it's a bit more elegant than messing with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, especially if they were set before.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another static way to get the number of available threads for my template?

The answer is *NO*, because [std::thread::hardware_concurrency()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) is not a *constexpr* function (the number of concurrent threads might vary depending on the system where the program works, so it is absolutely logical, right?), but `num_threads` must be initialized with a compile-time constant.

You might deal with some workarounds like using `std::vector` instead of array:

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass()
        : values(std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
    {}

private:
    std::vector<T> values;
};
```

Comment: Unrelated bit. While going through the standard, I find it weird that [`std::hardware_concurrency`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) isn't `constexpr` while [`std::hardware_constructive_interference_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size) is `constexpr`.

Comment: @WhiZTiM that's actually **very** reasonable. `..interferanace_size` 1) must be compile-time for the primary use of controlling memory layouts, e.g. with `alignas`. 2) can practically be determined somewhat reliably at compile-time - see also http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0154r0.html